# show only part of the original image of an image view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a list view and I have an image in it, the image just for example say is  1920 by 1080, and i only want to display the same amount of the image as height of the layout that it is in.

So i have a verticl linearLayout and it's height is 100dp for example, so i want the image that im using in that image view to display whatever 100 dp would translate onto the image? if that makes sense. I want to keep the same resolution and i dont want to shrink it or anything, just show part of the image .

this is the xml as of now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/example"
             />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:scaleType="center"
```

[Documentation to "center"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

[Documentation to "layout_weight"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

Comment: nothing is showing up for that? seems like its in the right direction though